# Can two state-changing transactions be in a single block?

Tags: transactions, contract-invocation

I don't know how Ethereum verifies the atomicity of the state of a contract in the mining process.

Say I have a greet-counting contract.

If two people call the greet function in (almost) the same time, can both transactions be included in a single block and the counter be incremented by two?

Or only one transaction will included in a block and the other will be left in the queue for the following block? Or, the worst case, the other transaction will even be thrown away?